# C++ Assigning Deferenced memory allocation using 'new'

Tags: c++

I am new to pointers. Wanted some help as to what the below snippet of code means. Account is a class.

```
Account a2 = *(new Account(123));
```

I understand that new returns an address to an object of type Account. Now when we dereference this using the '*' operator and pass this value to a2 what does a2 get and is this object created by new still present in the heap?

Also,  do we need a copy constructor to be defined in the Class Account for this type of assignment?

Comment: The object created by `new` is on the heap. It gets copied to `a2`. The code throws away the pointer returned by `new`, so the heap object cannot be accessed afterwards. This is called a memory leak; it's a serious mistake.

Comment: you can do (although you shouldn't) something like:
A& a= *new A;
delete &a;
and not leak this way

Comment: @PeteBecker I think your comment is good enough to be posted as an answer.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
Account a2 = *(new Account(123));
```

You create a new `Account` object on the free store, this object requires to be `delete`d through the pointer given to you from `new` otherwise there's a memory leak.

The current code dereferences that pointer returned from `new` and copies the `Account` object into a stack-based `Account` object `a2`. This means that the pointer is lost and thus there's a memory leak because you can never `delete` it anymore.

Comment: Thanks. Also, do we need a copy constructor to be defined in the Class Account for this type of assignment?

Comment: It depends on the contents of the class, but the default generated copy and assignment operators may be sufficient.